# Comparing subset of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if there is nice way to compare a subset of rows in pandas?
let's say I have a df with:

| id | in_test | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | 5 |
| 2 | True | 5 |
| 1 | False | 7 |
| 2 | False | 8 |

I would like the resulting df with id and difference (or percentage change) from in_test from true to false.

I know I could pivot the table and then perform row wise calculations, or create a filtered df and merge it with another filtered df and then compute it row wise.

I was wondering if there is python way of doing this in one line? With probably a pandas function?

The output for percentage diff would be :

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | +40% |
| 2 | +60% |

The output for diff would be :

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

(or minus -2 & -3 i guess I would have top define some kind of order) )

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: (I can't figure out why it's not rendering it properly )

Comment: Once you have grouped by `id`, you may find [.diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) or [.ediff1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html) helpful.

Comment: Do you always have 1 True and False per group?

Comment: Yes i have  True and False  but i would like the solution to work for a multitude of things time series, numbers or boolean

Comment: Can you give such examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().values[1]).reset_index()
```

difference

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change().values[1] * 100).reset_index()
```

percentage difference